# How to start BroadcastReceiver in boot?

Tags: java, android

I have an application that start every day at 10 o'clock, and everything Work fine. But when device reboot BroadcastReceiver doesn't work because app terminated then I start app in boot. When I set it to start in Boot (I mean start BroadcastReceiver) then BroadcastReceiver don't work correctly.

I mean my app start automatically in boot, but the time of app to start is 10 o'clock.

This my code

AndroidMaifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/aps"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/aps"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>



    <receiver android:name=".Tasks">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

</application>
```

Mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setRecurringAlarm(this);
}
private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {

        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:00"));
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tasks.class);
        PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(
                Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, recurringDownload);
    }
}
```

BroadCastReciver

```
public class Tasks extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i(ONE_TIME, "Executed Tasks.Java File");

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName(context, Main2Activity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two different `BroadcastReceiver`. One for `alarm` receiver and another for `boot` complete.

**Here is your `BootCompletedReceiver`:**

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:00"));
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tasks.class);
        PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(
                Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, recurringDownload);
    }
}
```

**Update your `AndroidManifest.xml` as below:**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/aps"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/aps"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>


    <receiver android:name=".Tasks">

    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: now app don't work correctly but after reboot work prefecttly my problem is app don't work before we restart phone how to solve it ? @fat

Comment: Try using PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); ... Check my updated answer

Comment: Use>> PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); both in BootCompletedReceiver and MainActivity when create an alarm.

Comment: @MohammadHosseinjfp If my answer seems useful then mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You defined the same `Receiver` both for the `Alarm` in your activity and for `BOOT_COMPLETED` event; So when the **alarm trigger** or **system boot** the same class is called (Which Start the Main Activity).

You need to define two `Receiver`. One to **Receive Alarm** and One to **Set Alarm** on **Boot Complete**, for Example:

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:00"));
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tasks.class);
        PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(
                Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, recurringDownload);
    }
}
```

, and for your `Alarm` Receiver you can have your old Receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i(ONE_TIME, "Executed Tasks.Java File");

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName(context, Main2Activity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Urw, Sometimes it helps to get someone to look at your code ^^

Comment: now app don't work correctly but after reboot work prefecttly my problem is app don't work before we restart phone how to solve it ? @Keivan Esbati

Comment: Just pop another question and copy the link here ^^

Comment: i couldn't ask another question @kievan Esbati

Comment: @MohammadHosseinjfp is the code above all the code you run in your app? What doesn't work correctly?

Comment: no alarm come in 10 o'clock but when i reboot mobile and turn it on work perfectlly

Comment: my alram set at 3 i know that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145157/discussion-between-keivan-esbati-and-mohammad-hossein-jfp).